# Error found - too many arguments to method call expected 1 have 2 - in app email

Tags: xcode4.3

There seems to be an error with my coding, and it says that there are to many nils or something
I need help

```
MFMailComposeViewController *composer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc]init];
if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {

    [composer setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"nicole@aandtlegal.com", nil]];
    [composer setSubject:nil];[composer setMailComposeDelegate:self];
    [composer setMessageBody:nil isHTML:YES];
    [composer setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;
[picker setSubject:@"Hello!"];
NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"example@example.com"]; 
[picker setToRecipients:toRecipients];
NSString *emailBody = [NSString stringWithString:@"Hello!"];
[picker setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:YES];
picker.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
[picker release];
```

Comment: Thanks for that, but straight after I posted this, i realized that I put array With object when I was supposed to put array with objects

Comment: That's OK. Thanks for letting me know and if you'd like to accept my answer, please fell free to do so.